# How did the Silence know about Melody?

Tags: doctor-who

Some way along the way in season 5 Amy Pond becomes pregnant...

> Fast forward and we find out that the silence have stolen her baby, brainwashed her and set her on the doctor.

How long had they been planning that? How did they know Amy would give birth to a

> Pseudo-timelord?

Had they been planning this all along or was it opportunistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of those timey-wimey wibbly-wobbly things.

They didn't need to find out about Melody Pond at the time Amy was pregnant; they could find out at any later time and then go back and (attempt to) engineer the time line in the way they wanted.

It could very well be that they found out about Melody Pond because the archeologist River Song was sent to prison for killing a very good man, and then set out to kidnap the child and turn her into a killer. Kind of a cause & effect closed loop.

Comment: So Amy's pregnancy was unplanned? Because Amy says in later episodes "Whatever they [the silence] did to me at Demon's run meant...." so I assumed they had planned the whole shenanigans.

Comment: @Pureferret: They were messing with Melody's DNS at Demon's Run, but Melody was conceived on Amy and Rory's wedding night.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very certain about this, but I guess Amy-Rory were the first couple to have been companions whilst being actively engaged (Rose and Mikey were no longer in a relationship when they traveled together, also they were never shown to be romantically involved in any of the further episodes when the traveled together).
The Silence would need a child that was conceived on the TARDIS itself. This made Amy-Rory an easy option for them. So they must have planned it out over the centuries.